# The following SQL insert statement works in Microsoft SQL Server but not in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm new to MySQL and trying to convert code that works in Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL. The SELECT statement below works in MySQL but not the INSERT INTO.  Is there a different format for an INSERT INTO with an aggregate statement (AVG) for MySQL?

```
-- Adding data to the Health Data Baseline table

INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline (
    Total_Sleep_Duration_Baseline
    ,Body_Weight_Baseline
    ,Body_Mass_Index_Baseline
    ,Body_Fat_Percentage_Baseline
    ,Step_Count_Baseline
    ,Flights_Climbed_Baseline
    ,Health_Data.Person_Device_ID)
SELECT 
    AVG(Total_Sleep_Duration) -- as "Average Minutes of Sleep Per Night"
    ,AVG(Body_Weight) -- as "Average Weight in Pounds"
    ,AVG(Body_Mass_Index) -- as "Average Body Mass Index"
    ,AVG(Body_Fat_Percentage) -- as "Average Body Fat %"
    ,AVG(Step_Count) -- as "Average Step Count"
    ,AVG(Flights_Climbed) -- as "Average Flights Climbed"
    ,Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
FROM Health_Data 
JOIN Person_Device ON Person_Device.Person_Device_ID = Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
GROUP BY Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
```

Comment: give us an error message

Comment: Something seems off about this column `Health_Data.Person_Device_ID` in your `Health_Data_Baseline` table. I have edited your post and formatted your query to make this more obvious.

Comment: Are you sure that works in sql server? You have the last column as "Health_Data.Person_Device_ID" which I am almost certain would fail in sql server.

Comment: As @SeanLange noted, this will throw an error in SQL Server if you do have a column name with a period in it and you haven't included additional formatting (i.e. square brackets) like so `[Health_Data.Person_Device_ID]`.

Comment: @SeanLange Weirdly, it works - SQL Server seems to just ignore the part before the `.`

Comment: @JacobH I assumed so, as well, but I just tried it. You can actually write complete nonsense before the `.` and SQL Server will ignore it and insert into the column. e.g. `CREATE TABLE #FOO ( ID INT ); INSERT INTO #FOO ( NonsenseThatWillBeIgnored.ID ) VALUES ( 42 ); SELECT * FROM #FOO`

Comment: You cannot insert into Health_Data.Person_Device_ID when inserting into health_data_baseline

Comment: @IMSoP Oh nevermind, I see the difference. I actually created the column with the period to test. This query does not run `CREATE TABLE #BAR ( [Test.Something] INT);
INSERT INTO #BAR (  Test.Something )
VALUES(42)` However, this does: `CREATE TABLE #BAR ( [Test.Something] INT);
INSERT INTO #BAR (  [Test.Something] )
VALUES('42')`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick (and accurate) responses.  I removed the "Health_Data" from 'Health_Data.Person_Device_ID" and the code now works in MySQL.  I also went back to SQL Server to test the original code and it works but I agree that the prefix "Health_Data" should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a subtle bug in your `INSERT` statement; taking away the other columns to make it more obvious, you have:

```
INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline (
    Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
)
SELECT 
    Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
FROM Health_Data 
GROUP BY Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
```

That first `Health_Data.Person_Device_ID` should just be specifying the column `Person_Device_ID` in the target table (`Health_Data_Baseline`). Qualifying it with a table name makes no sense.

For some reason, SQL Server ignores this prefix - you can actually write `INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline ( CompleteNonsenseThatMeansNothing.Person_Device_ID )` - but other DBMSes will reject it as invalid syntax.

In other words, just change it to:

```
INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline (
    Person_Device_ID
)
SELECT 
    Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
FROM Health_Data 
GROUP BY Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Should that be..

```
INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline (
    Total_Sleep_Duration_Baseline
    ,Body_Weight_Baseline
    ,Body_Mass_Index_Baseline
    ,Body_Fat_Percentage_Baseline
    ,Step_Count_Baseline
    ,Flights_Climbed_Baseline
    ,Person_Device_ID)
```

Above, you are indicating which fields of `Health_Data_Baseline` you want to INSERT on, however, I doubt you have a field named

```
Health_Data_Baseline.Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

MYSQL version of code need square brackets when "Something.Something" format mentioned in inserted to columns as it is not as much typing friendly:
i.e.

```
INSERT INTO Health_Data_Baseline (
Total_Sleep_Duration_Baseline
,Body_Weight_Baseline
,Body_Mass_Index_Baseline
,Body_Fat_Percentage_Baseline
,Step_Count_Baseline
,Flights_Climbed_Baseline
,[Health_Data.Person_Device_ID])
```

SELECT 
    AVG(Total_Sleep_Duration) -- as "Average Minutes of Sleep Per Night"
    ,AVG(Body_Weight) -- as "Average Weight in Pounds"
    ,AVG(Body_Mass_Index) -- as "Average Body Mass Index"
    ,AVG(Body_Fat_Percentage) -- as "Average Body Fat %"
    ,AVG(Step_Count) -- as "Average Step Count"
    ,AVG(Flights_Climbed) -- as "Average Flights Climbed"
    ,Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
FROM Health_Data 
JOIN Person_Device ON Person_Device.Person_Device_ID = Health_Data.Person_Device_ID
GROUP BY Health_Data.Person_Device_ID

Comment: Check the existing answers and comments; SQL Server would also need quotes of some sort if the column actually had a . in its name.

Comment: @IMSOP Of-course I saw your answer, but with due respect it was not clear and elaborative so I wrote my answer with complete query for the ease of asker and readers. And why telling me I have not said " *.* works in SQL Server", it is quoted in your own answer.

Comment: If the name of the column was actually `Health_Data.Person_Device_ID`, the query given would not work in Microsoft SQL Server without adding the `[` and `]` as you show here. Since the question says it *does* work in SQL Server, we know that this isn't the problem. The problem is that *the column is actually called `Person_Device_ID`*, but the insert statement has a mistake, which for some reason SQL Server ignores.